# Como acessar banco de dados fire bird de outra máquina sem ser do servidor

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebird, localhost, powerbi, odbc

Tenho um banco de dados firebird que está em um computador, nesse mesmo computador eu fiz  uma configuração odbc  configurei e deu certo. porém eu preciso me conectar a esse servidor  no power bi em outro computador como eu posso fazer isso?

Eu entendo que precisa usar esse modelo DRIVER=InterBase/Firebird(r) driver;User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=localhost:C:/AdCom/ADCOM.FDB";

porém como eu referencio a outra máquina ?

Comment: Duplicações não são aceitas neste site. Se tem algum complemento ou melhoria, faça na [postagem oriiginal](/q/593334/70) clicando em "restaurar", caso necessário, e em editar. Para evitar descentralização de informações o espaço de comentários foi desativado (apenas nessa segunda postagem - na original, se restaurada, está disponível).